# How to oscillate and tween between multiple number states?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tween

I would like to be able to do something similair to what Mike Bostock does in his second example in the documentation for .textTween. I've managed to do a lot of work towards solving this, but I can't quite get it right. I'm completely new to JavaScript so perhaps thats the problem.

In the case of the [observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@d3/transition-texttween), the number oscilates between different random variables, which are assigned to the _current parameter for the next oscillation. How would I do this with only two numbers, which I would like to go back and forth between?

I tried working it into some code like this but to no avail -

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 960)
        .attr("height", 500);

function textrepeat() {

    var textrepeat = svg.append("text")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("class", "txt")
        .attr("x", 30)
        .attr("y", 30)
    repeat();

    function repeat() {
      textrepeat
        .text("300")      
        .transition()        
        .duration(2000)
        .tweening ???   //here is where to insert it?
        .text("1000")    
        .transition()        
        .duration(2000)      
        .text("300")    
        .on("end", repeat);  
    };

};

textrepeat();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, all you need is two `textTween` functions. For instance, going from `300` to `1000` and back:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");

function textrepeat() {

  var textrepeat = svg.append("text")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("y", 50);

  repeat();

  function repeat() {
    textrepeat.transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .textTween(function() {
        return function(t) {
          return ~~d3.interpolate(300, 1001)(t)
        };
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .textTween(function() {
        return function(t) {
          return ~~d3.interpolate(1001, 300)(t)
        };
      })
      .on("end", repeat);
  };

};

textrepeat();
```

```css
text {
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: `transition.textTween` was added in D3 v5.14. If you're using a previous version, change it for `.tween("text", function() { etc...`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'm now trying to attach that data to circles that vary in size as the value of the text tweens, any advice for that?

Comment: @StupidQuestionGuy no, I'm not following it. The best idea is posting a new question, with all the relevant details.